# Chromatic CLI not building storybook

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, storybook, chromatic

I am not able to get chromatic cli v5.4.0 to build my storybook. It worked the first time and then hangs on subsequent attempts.

```
  ➜  my-project git:(storybook-poc) ✗ yarn chromatic
  yarn run v1.22.10
$ npx chromatic --project-token xxxfooxxx

Chromatic CLI v5.4.0
https://www.chromatic.com/docs/cli

  ✔ Authenticated with Chromatic
    → Using project token '*******xxx'
  ✔ Retrieved git information
    → Commit 'f392eff' on branch 'storybook-poc'; found 1 baseline commit
  ✔ Collected Storybook metadata
    → Storybook v6.1.3 for React; supported addons found: Actions, Backgrounds, Docs, Links, Viewport
  ⠼ Building your Storybook
    → Running command: build-storybook -- --output-dir /var/folders/1t/9d_7zrws2p52d2gw918m16wr0000gq/T/chromatic--50970-DBkh6i7fBaPe
    Publish your built Storybook
    Verify your Storybook
    Take snapshots of your stories
```

The output of that var directory never contains anything more then the following, despite leaving running for several minutes:

```
ls -la /var/folders/1t/9d_7zrws2p52d2gw918m16wr0000gq/T/chromatic--50970-DBkh6i7fBaPe

total 0
drwx------    2 stefan  staff    64  1 Dec 15:50 .
drwx------@ 190 stefan  staff  6080  1 Dec 15:51 ..
```

I am working around this for now by using the following command, so perhaps something permissions based ‍♂️. Suggestions welcome!

```
./node_modules/.bin/chromatic --project-token=xxxxfooxxxx
```

Comment: Try running `yarn build-storybook` directly. Does that successfully build a static version of your Storybook?

Comment: Yes, building the storybook directly in yarn is ok, but as an artefact of the chromatic build it just hangs. Also raised here: https://github.com/chromaui/chromatic-cli/issues/213#issuecomment-754989987

Comment: Thanks, I've released a potential fix in `chromatic@5.5.1-dev.0`. Can you verify it works?

Comment: Awesome, I can confirm that the upgrade to `chromatic@5.5.1-dev.0` has fixed this for my local build. Many thanks!

Comment: Getting the same issue in latest (version 5.7.0)

Running it via `./node_modules/.bin/chromatic --project-token=XXX` worked fine.



This is my build-storybook.log when trying to install via npx
`Starting: build-storybook -- --output-dir /var/folders/n5/wh9lxxj95dbg6nxntqzbx11m0000gn/T/chromatic--18123-7erHXFOO14gh
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:926
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/braydencowell/Documents/ui-library/build-storybook'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:15)
    at Function.Module._load
}`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to `chromatic@5.5.1-dev.0` as per @Gert_Hengeveld comment has remedied the issue for build. Many thanks!

```
yarn chromatic
yarn run v1.22.5
$ npx chromatic --project-token ******

Chromatic CLI v5.5.1-dev.1
https://www.chromatic.com/docs/cli

✔ Authenticated with Chromatic
→ Using project token '**********'
✔ Retrieved git information
→ Commit '5aaa9bc' on branch 'CON-91-deploy-to-prod'; found 1 baseline commit
✔ Collected Storybook metadata
→ Storybook v6.1.3 for React; supported addons found: Actions, Backgrounds, Docs, Links, Viewport
✔ Storybook built in 1 minute 5 seconds
→ View build log at /Users/MEH/code/.../build-storybook.log
✔ Publish complete in 16 seconds
→ View your Storybook at https://5fc......0c1-mk...dy.chromatic.com
✔ Started build 7
→ View build details at https://www.chromatic.com/build?appId=5fc......0c1&number=7
✔ Build 7 failed after 10 seconds
```

Comment: Happy to learn it worked! I'll make sure it's in the next release.